# Какой драйвер использовать для подключения к MS SQL Server в Qt?

Tags: qt, sql-server

Какой драйвер использовать для подключения к MS SQL Server в Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QODBC!

Пример:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QODBC" );
db.setDatabaseName( "DRIVER={SQL Native Client};Server=my_pc_name;Database=my_db_name;Trusted_Connection=yes;" );
```